# Roslyn - How can I get all references of a variable at DiagnosticAnalyzer class?

Tags: c#, refactoring, roslyn

I'm currently trying to define a code fix with Roslyn. I have a `SyntaxNode` variable.

I would like to find all references of that variable at my `DiagnosticAnalyzer` class. Unfortunately `SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync` method requires a `Solution` parameter, and if I know well, I can't get the current solution from `DiagnosticAnalyzer` class.

How can I get all references of a variable at `DiagnosticAnalyzer` class?

Comment: When you say "variable", do you mean a local variable declared using a `LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax` ? If so, its scope is limited to the member in which it is declared. It should be easy to search that for all usages.

Comment: That being said, what do you need those for? Are you sure you cannot use `context.SemanticModel.AnalyzeDataFlow(localDeclaration)` ?

Comment: When I say "variable" I mean IdentifierNameSyntax. I try to create a code fix for forgotten disposes. But in the following scenario I need references for dispose checks:
myIDisposable = new MyIDisposable();
var tmp = myIDispoable;
tmp.Dispose();

Comment: `IdentifierNameSyntax` is just a name. My question is what that name refers to. Only local variables? Given your use case, I assume you only need to look at local variables indeed, not fields or parameters. So that means you can search the enclosing member.

Comment: SonarLint has a couple of analyzers on disposables. In general this topic is difficult. What do you do with disposable locals that are returned from a method. What do you do with fields? What do you do with disposables that are passed to other disposables in their constructor? ...

Comment: I would like to know the most common case. Which works for local variables, fields and parameters as well. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe [Code Cracker](https://github.com/code-cracker/code-cracker) already has what you want. If not, it might help you in your implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented a similar Analyzer, the algorithm was the following (it ran for ~31ms on a 2000+ line Document, but almost always under 10 ms)

1. Iterate through all nodes in `SemanticModel.GetRoot()` and collect Expressions and LocalDeclarations
2. Get the symbol of the corresponding Identifier
3. Check if it implements `IDisposable`, store in `HashSet1` if it does
4. Iterate through Invocations where the method invoked is Dispose
5. Get the symbol from Invocation, store in `HashSet2`
6. Report Diagnostic on the first `SyntaxReference` of Symbols that are in `HashSet1` but not in `HashSet2`

This works well, but sadly I do not know if there is a more efficient / cleaner way of doing this. I can share parts of the code if you like.